New keyframe is not retaining instructed transform postion change
I've been using Blender happily for a while now but have encountered odd behaviour.
Keyframing was never an issue until now, but whenever I reposition an object thus creating a new keyframe, when I move away from said frame and back the values have reset to the preceding keyframe.
Here's an unlisted video demonstrating the issue.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
EDIT:
Here's a WeTransfer link containing a minimum number of files in a zip folder. It's about 71MB.

Looks odd, can you upload the file (or a simplified version of it)?

Do you use Blender version 4.0 or below? Then have a look at my answer. Otherwise if this does not help we might need your file as @joshsanfelici suggested.

Please upload a file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your scene. Why is a minimal version file a size of 71 MB? As I understand it this is just a single plane moving up and down... to test the keyframing we don't any other objects or textures etc.

Cheers, I'll upload after I've made dinner. I thought it best to include the video file that is imported for the keyframing I was trying to achieve, but happy to remove it from the folder if it isn't needed. Thanks again.

It's okay, I've used the other file. Generally the video file is not important for us to check the keyframing in itself, because setting keyframes on an object should be possible no matter what video is showing on the plane. Sure it might be important to decide where to place keyframes, but not for the issue of placing keyframes per se.

Taking another look at your video I realised that when you go to frame 231, the playhead (the vertical blue line) is not showing up. Here a comparison how it looks like in your file vs. how it should look like:

Zooming out I found it at frame 77 (actually ≈ 76.7). Which means when you set a keyframe at 231, then the object will be at the new position if you just move the playhead far enough so that it reaches frame 231.
Now why is this happening? Under Output Properties > Frame Range you have (for whatever reason) set the Time Stretching values from Old = 200 to New = 600 instead of the default 100 for both. Which means they get multiplied by a factor of 600/200 = 3.

The problem is now, the keyframes will be set at the frame numbers which are showing. But the playhead has not yet reached this frame because to get to 230 you have to move it to 230 × 3 = 690. And the next keyframe is set on 231, so to get there you have to go to frame 231 × 3 = 693.
The keyframes in the Dope Sheet, Time Line, Graph Editor etc. are displayed on "unstretched time", but the playhead moves on "stretched" time.
As long as there are only keyframes on a single frame you do not notice the discrepancy, because a single keyframe on a channel sets this value for all frames before and after this keyframe. So a keyframe on 230 is theoretically valid from -infinity to infinity as long as there is no other keyframe, and it always looks the same no matter if your playhead is at 230 or 230/3 ≈ 76.7 or 230 × 3 = 690.
But as soon as you set a keyframe on frame 231 and expect a change if you switch from 230 to 231, then you see the problem: the keyframes are at 230 and 231 in unstretched time, which means they affect the movement of the object from frame 690 to 693. But when you are on frame 231, the playhead is at 231/3 = 77, far below 690 and that is why it will show the starting position until you move past 690.
If you really need this Time Stretching you have to take it into account when placing keyframes. If you don't need it simply set it back to 100/100 or 1/1 or whatever value you want, as long as Old and New are the same and their ratio is 1:1.

That's wonderful. Thank you so much. I might pop this solution into a short youtube video, and I'll cite you and both of your answers if I do.

Unfortunately the hierarchy is not expanded in the video. Therefore the only idea I have now is that the Z location channel might be accidentally locked so that it does not store new keyframes:

However this depends on which version you are using. In Blender 4.1 when the keyframe shortcut was changed so that I now sets a keyframe for all transformation channels instead of bringing up the keyframe menu to choose channels, they also changed the Auto Keying behavior: instead of setting a keyframe on all channels, only the one that was changed gets a new keyframe.
This means, in your case there would not appear a new keyframe in the Summary, because if the only channel you changed is locked, then no new keyframe will be set. But if you are using Blender 4.0 or an older version, all other channels except for the Z location will get a keyframe despite not being changed, so the Summary will show a new keyframe on that frame which would explain your issue.

Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I'm using 4.1 and as far as I can tell no location channel is locked. I'll add an image of the expanded hierarchy to the original post.

@Docconcoct Okay, I'll just leave my answer here for anybody who might have this problem. Looking at your expanded hierarchy, obviously not only is the channel not locked but it also shows a keyframe there... maybe we really need your file to check more in detail.

Cool, I'm readying a minimal version to share now. I'll get in up shortly. Cheers.
